# ShakeGestures - .dll file missing

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I'm dowloading the `ShakeGesture`-library from [MSDN](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/Recipe_Shake_Gesture_Library), they tell me to reference the .DLL file. But when I unzip the folder, all I get is the source code and a lengthy document on how everything works. Now, where can I get this .dll file? If anyone can link it to me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the project in VS, either rebuild or run the application. It will then make the dll in projectpath\obj\Debug